# Set Parameter in SPFILE still outputs the same error

Tags: sqlplus, oracle-18c, suse-linux

for the installation of a SAP IDM system, I need to know how to use the command `alter system set "_ORACLE_SCRIPT"=true SCOPE=SPFILE;` command correctly.

The installation creates a user and gives the error `ORA-65096: "invalid common user or role name"`. During the researches I found the command `alter session set "_ORACLE_SCRIPT"=true`. This command allows to create users temporarly.
At the next session or in a separate terminal, this is no longer possible.

In the `$ORACLE_HOME/dbs/spfile.ora` the parameter `*_oracle_script=true` was in there, but it gives me the same error again.

Thank you in advance.

-Sruscht

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Digging further: Your error indicates that you are using a container/pluggable database (CDB/PDB) architecture for your Oracle Database. The SAP IDM installation guide specifically says *not* to do this:

> When installing the Identity Management database on Oracle, note the following prerequisites and recommendations:...
>
> ...make sure the Create as Container database option is not selected

https://help.sap.com/viewer/d77277f42c0b469db8794645abd954ea/8.0/en-US/571119cc37ce465b93de726fc0408427.html

Based on this, you will most likely need to recreate your database from scratch and make sure it is configured as a traditional instance, and not as container/pluggable database architecture.

Comment: Hey @pmdba, thank you for the quick answer. I will restore a snapshot and look how i figure that out. Thank you.

Comment: You will need to recreate your database with the dbca utility. When asked if you want the Container Database option, make sure it is *not* selected.

Comment: While i recreated my database, I just went to the oracle-xe script and deselected the "Only a CDB"-option before i configure it. It worked!